# How can you export to external file ( .json or .csv or whatever ) list of pods from kubernetes

Tags: json, csv, kubectl

Is there a way to export list of pods that you get when you run command 'kubectl get pods -n name_of_your_namespace '? I am trying to automate some everyday work with PowerShell scripss and i would like to export list of running pods in namespace to json or csv, then check that json or csv files if those running pods are that I want and then to save names of those pods into variables and use them in other PowerShell scripts.

So for now I need just a way to export results that you get when 'kubectl get pods' command is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about this question. I've found solution to problem I had. The command was very simple.

```
kubectl get pods -o=name > $pathToFile(you desired path to file in format 'C:/Folder/test.csv' -n $namespace
```

And @DazWilkin, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The Below command will generate a csv file by having all columns

kubectl get pods -n mynamespace | tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' > output.csv